# Dynamic event handling in Android

Tags: java, android, event-handling

Normally in android what we do is we get the reference to the view, then set on click listener and then do a function.
What I want to do is, there are many gestures ( on touch, on long touch, etc ) that pass as parameters to the method and trigger a function based on the gesture passed.

Something like this:

```
public void doSomething(Event event, View view){

...do something

//if its onClick event that passed do something will trigger once user clicks it
//if its onLongClick event, the method will trigger for the onLongTap event

}
```

I have no idea to achieve this. Any help would be appreciated. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can implement `onTouch` You will have something like this:

```
public class YourView extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {

@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    //Here you can check for which movement is being made on a switch pattern. 
    //You can also call any gesture detector you might have

      mScaleDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      mRotationDetector.onTouchEvent(event);
      mGestureDetector.onTouchEvent(event);

      final int action = MotionEventCompat.getActionMasked(ev);
      switch (action) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        //Do stuff;
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        //Do stuff;
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        //Do stuff;
        break;
    return false;
    } 
}
```

I recommend you to read the documentation about [Gesture Detection](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/detector.html), they give you some examples on how to approach this.